# Bitshift to 64'th Bit in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

For a programm, i need to shift the bits from the first to the last bit.
So i would need to:

```
long a = 0;
a |= 1L<<64;
```

Since the `long` isn't `unsigned`, it doesn't work. Is there a possibility to shift a 1 to this last Bit? I'm taking a `long` and not a `BigInt`, because i'm tried to use as few memory than possible.

Comment: Try shifting by 63. Since long has 64 bits shifting 1 by 64 will result in 1 since Java actually shifts by `your_value % sizeof(type)` which means in your case it shifts by `64 % 64 = 0`.

Comment: Did you mean 63 instead? Because unless I'm mistaken, shifting it 64 would shirt it out of the length of the variable.

Comment: In fact `a |= 1L << 63` gives the result `-9223372036854775808` which is probably the correct answer

Comment: of course i thought 63, i need the long as a kind of "array" of bool values. But since the last bit is thought to "sign" the number, i can't reach it..

Comment: Signedness is irrelevant. A `long` does have 64 bits, and the 64th bit is "reached" with `1L << 63`. That that bit "is the sign" doesn't matter, it's still a bit.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one it is marked a duplicate of. The right answer to this question is "to get to the most significant bit of a long shift by 63, not 64".

Comment: Oh, i've got it.. My fault, sorry
Thank you all guys :)

Comment: @ruakh ok ok ;)

Answer (score 4):

Java will shift by `num % sizeof(datatype)` only, i.e. if you shift an `int` by `32` it will effectively be no shift at all. If you shift by 33 the effective shift will be `33 % 32 = 1`.

The same is true for `long` just that the size of `long` is 64 and thus shifting by 64 is effectively no shift. The highest shift possible with `long` thus is 63 and that's what you need to get the last bit to position 64 (it already *is* at position 1 so you just need to shift by 63 places).

Answer (score 1):

Shifting by 64 bits will have the effect of not shifting.
Shifting by 63 bits will have desired output.
Shift on `long` v << b shifts by b%64 bits. so 1L<<64 shifts by nothing.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    long a=1L<<63;
    long b=1L<<64;
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(a));
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(b));
}
```

Expected output:

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code doesn't make a lot of sense. If you shift a `long` variable 64 places to the left, you *should* end up with zero, since you've shifted away all of the `long`'s original bits.

Second, as you've correctly mentioned, Java treats all `int`s and `long`s as singed (as stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)). So it considers a 64 bit shift on a `long` to be equal to a 0 shift. That's why instead of getting zero, you're left with the original value, which is 1. If you want to initialize `a` to `1` followed by 63 zeroes I suggest avoiding shifts, and just using something like this:

`long a = 0x8000_0000_0000_0000L;`

It's readable by anyone who understands binary, and there's not Java bit shift magic involved.

If you want to keep using shift, just use a 6**3** shift instead:

```
long a|=1L<<63;
```